# How to cast Jdbc4Connection to PGConnection?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I want to make use of postgres `CopyManager` like:

```
CopyManager cp = ((PGConnection) dataSource.getConnection()).getCopyAPI();
```

As I'm using `spring-boot`, the datasource is a `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`, thus the connection a `Jdbc4Connection`.

Problem: The casting throws the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55 cannot be cast to org.postgresql.PGConnection
```

Also, when I try to cast to a Jdbc4Connection, I get the very same error!

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55 cannot be cast to org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection
```

What can I do?

Comment: Then what you have is not a PGConnection.

Comment: The datasource doesn't hand out the real connection, only a proxy. Check for a method `getPhysicalConnection()` or something similar in your connection pool

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes but I get the same error when casting to different connection.

Comment: That is because what you have is a proxy provided by your jdbc-pool, not the actual connection.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how should I do this? `((org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) dataSource).getPoolProperties().isAccessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed(); //true`, but how could I get that underlying connection?

Comment: If in doubt read the manual: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Getting_the_actual_JDBC_connection

Comment: Great , I see. Thanks! Would you mind adding this as an answer, as this is probably the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using javax.sql.DataSource then here is a solution:

```
if (dataSource.getConnection().isWrapperFor(PGConnection.class)) {
  PGConnection pgConnection = dataSource.getConnection().unwrap(PGConnection.class);
}
```

Hope this helps.